# Can you identify this dome

Tags: part-identification

Can anyone identify [this dome?](https://ramblingbrick.files.wordpress.com/2017/07/img_68461.jpg)  I looked through the "brick,round" section of bricklink and couldn't find it.

Comment: What really helps me when searching on Bricklink is searching the *dimensions*. In this case the measurement of the part is 4 studs (x axis) by 4 studs (y axis). In the BL search, that would be written as 4x4. If too many pages appear, try searching by other properties. For example If it has printed decoration you type "pattern" and BL will give printed parts, and if it has sticker you type sticker and you'll find what you want.

Comment: @mindstormsboi Dimensions on BL would be written with space like "4 x 4", and not "4x4". See your own answer.

Comment: @Alex I know that, but **that doesn't matter.** Bricklink will still think of it the same way. In fact, in order to find the piece, I typed it *without* spaces and still got what I was looking for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's [Cylinder Hemisphere 4 x 4](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=86500#T=C).

[image: yeah]